# Change the label's text everytime a button is pressed

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, button, tkinter, label

I'm doing a PYTHON table using FOR, in TKINTER, and I would like every time a new number is placed in ENTRY, the label changes to the new table. For example, a number will be placed in the ENTRY and the person will click the TAB button, when it is clicked, the table will appear, but if the person wants another number, and click again, the new table will go down from the previous one. My solution was to create a button that erases the previous table, but when the button is pressed, only the last multiplication is deleted. I would like to know how I click the tabuada button, and the previous one erases the new one without using another button .Get the code and a photo below, Thanks. Obs.: First photo shows reset button working, but it just erase the last multiplication,second photo shows the whole multiplication.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

win=tk.Tk()
win.title('Table')
lb=Label(win,text='Type a number:',font='Helvetica 12 bold')
lb.pack()
e=Entry(win)
e.pack()

def click():
   global c
   c=e.get()
   print('requested number ',c)

for b in (range(0, 11)):
   global lb2
   lb2=Label(text='{} x {} = {} '.format(c, b, int(b)*int(c)))
   lb2.pack()

def reset():
   lb2['text'] = ' '

bt1=Button(win,text='GO',bg='lightblue',command=click)
bt1.pack()
bt2=Button(win,text='RESET',bg='lightblue',command=reset)   
bt2.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

erasing:

[image: erasing]

whole multiplication:

[image: whole multiplication]

Comment: i really need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some fixes for your code; it was not entirely clear what you exactly meant by: *"the new table will go down from the previous one."*, so I went with having the new table replacing the previous one.

`c` was not defined in your code and that threw an exception.
I placed the construction of the label inside a function `make_label` that is called from the `main` block, and from `click()`, to rebuild it when a new number is requested.
`reset` was missing a call to `pack` on the label, to update the text displayed.

I think that should help you get started in the right direction; let me know if something is unclear.

## edit:

I modified `reset` so the label is destroyed and re-created from view, thus removing the growth in size of the window.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

win=tk.Tk()
win.title('Table')
lb=Label(win,text='Type a number:',font='Helvetica 12 bold')
lb.grid(row=0, column=0)
lb2 = Label(text='')
e=Entry(win)
e.grid(row=1, column=0)
c = 2

def click():
    global c
    c = e.get()
    print('requested number ', c)
    reset()
    make_label(c)

def make_label(c):
    global lb2
    txt = []
    for b in (range(0, 11)):
        txt.append('{} x {} = {} '.format(c, b, int(b)*int(c)))
    text = '\n'.join(txt)
    lb2 = Label(text=text)
    lb2.grid(row=4, column=0)

def reset():
    global lb2
    lb2.destroy()
    lb2 = Label()
    lb2.grid(row=4, column=0)

make_label(c)

bt1=Button(win,text='GO',bg='lightblue',command=click)
bt1.grid(row=2, column=0)
bt2=Button(win,text='RESET',bg='lightblue',command=reset)   
bt2.grid(row=3, column=0)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's great! 
Exactly what I wanted, now the main objective is to solve the space problem and the button OK, every time I click in button OK,  create a new multiplication,  but its created below the previous multiplication, and when I press RESET,  just the last multiplication is erased,  I want to click on button OK,  and erase the current multiplication,  to create another,  but you don't how you helped me,  I'm so thankful!!

Comment: I changed from `pack` to `grid` layout manager in order to have better control over the placement of the label and the size of the window. It is better now.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I dind't think about using destroy(), and now on i'll use grid instead of pack, it's more manageable than pack, i have no words to thank you, really, you made my idea become true, thank you so much again, it's working perfectly!!

Comment: Now that you are satisfied, you should accept this answer, and maybe upvote it too.

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer Sr Robles ; just over the green tick, on the top left of the answer, there is a group of 3 items: an upwards pointing triangle, a number, and a downward pointing triangle. If you click on the upwards pointing triangle (thhe one on th etop), you will upvote.